# How to create a dropdown list dynamically using Vuejs? Or any general component

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been trying to dynamically add a Vue component into my template while the app is running. I know that fundamentally, people usually prefer not to use this type of concept with Vuejs but my current project requires me to do it.

Let's look at a simplified code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <object-container>
            <-- I basically want to add a component here -->
        </object-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

For example once the user clicks on a button, or changes a certain option from the application. My application needs to generate new components according to the input. For our sake, let's assume that we only want to generate a single dropdown list.

Example would be something like: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

However, this needs to be generated dynamically and the options will come from the inputs of the application.

Beyond the simple example of select and options. How can I dynamically generate a vue component that I have created? For example, if I make a component called `myDropDown`, how can I generate this component dynamically similar to the simple `select` example? I would assume that it is fairly similar.

Basically I want a functionality similar to jQuery like in this question: [How to create dropdown list dynamically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814512/how-to-create-dropdown-list-dynamically-using-jquery)

**Edit:**

I wanted to add some questions similar to mine, unfortunately, none of these really give an answer, I really have no choice but to dynamically generate new components that can not be previously prepared.

[append vue js component using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540219/append-vue-js-component-using-jquery/43544657)

[Append dynamic vue component after specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428266/append-dynamic-vue-component-after-specific-element)

There are more examples that have a very similar question, and my question can be tagged as duplicate but I couldn't find any solutions at all.

Comment: No one working in Vue has a problem dynamically adding components or elements to the page, we simply recommend not doing it with jQuery or any other method of manipulating the DOM directly. There is likely some state that is driving whether or not you should render a select, and you should build your template accordingly. Build the template as a reflection of state.

Comment: A very basic example. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MBgLJa

Comment: Thank you for the nice example but it seems that the "template" in your example is fixed. Can I change the template dynamically?

Comment: What do you want to change?

Answer (score 3):

You can try use the following code

```js
Vue.component('my-row', {
   props: ['title'],
   template:`<option>{{title}}</option>`,
})
new Vue({
  el: '#box-select',
  data:{
   newTodoText: '',
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Do the dishes',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Take out the trash',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Mow the lawn'
      }
    ]
  },
   methods:{

     onChange(key) {
       this.newTodoText = "id:"+this.items[key-1].id+"/title:"+this.items[key-1].title;
  }

   }
  
  
  
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="box-select">
  <select @change="onChange($event.target.value)">
      <option 

        is="my-row"
        v-for="item in items"
    v-bind:title="item.title"
    v-bind:value="item.id"
    
      >
    </option>
  </select>
   <!--  <view-option v-for="item in items" :item="item" :key="item.id"></view-option> -->
  {{newTodoText}}
</div>
```

Comment: I see how this would allow me to change the options. However, I need to be able to do this for many different components not just dropdowns/selects, do I need to wrap them like this with a separate Vue component every single time? To be able to modify them dynamically?

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it but I will research a bit more before I accept it as an answer.